# Find indices of white space characters in a string

Tags: performance, strings, swift

This function returns the indices of all white spaces as an array of Integer. It works fine with a small string:

```
func whiteSpacesIndices(value : String) -> Array<Int> {
    var indices: Array<Int> = []
    for (index, char) in value.enumerated() {
        if char == " " || char == "\n" || char == "\t" {
            indices.append(index)
        }
    }
    return indices
}
```

However when the string is too long, it could be very slow, because it is looping in every character.

Is there a better way for doing it?

Comment: How long is the string tested? Could you please give the character count and the number of spaces?

Comment: With a string that has `8447` characters and `1307` spaces, your code takes 0.5ms on my machine

Comment: This returns integral positions of white space, but they're not indices, per say. I.e., they cannot be used to index back into the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General remarks

- `value`, as a parameter name, isn't very descriptive,
- The code considers that white spaces can only be `" "` or `"\n"` or `"\t"`. This a performance optimization and supposes prior knowledge of the contents of the string. More generally you could make the check this way:

  ```
  if char.isWhitespace {
      indices.append(index)
  }
  ```
- `Array<Int>` is not the same as `[String.Index]` of [IndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset). A `String` can be traversed using `String.Index` and not and `Int`.

### Performance

The following codeis twice as fast in my tests, but doesn’t work with emoji :

```
func whiteSpacesIndices(in str : String) -> Array<Int> {
    var indices: Array<Int> = []
    let blanks: [UInt32] = [32, 10, 9]  //these values correspond to space, new line, and tabulation respectively.
    for (index, scalar) in str.unicodeScalars.enumerated() {
        if blanks.contains(scalar.value) {
            indices.append(index)
        }
    }
    return indices
}
```

You can learn more about the Unicode scalar representation [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID304).

## Free function or instance method?

The `whiteSpacesIndices` function seems more like a property on strings. It is appropriate for a String to know about the indices of white spaces (and new lines) within itself:

```
extension String {
    var whiteSpaceIndices: [Int] {
        var indices = [Int]()
        let blanks: [UInt32] = [32, 10, 9]
        for (index, scalar) in self.unicodeScalars.enumerated() {
            if blanks.contains(scalar.value) {
                indices.append(index)
            }
        }
        return indices
    }
}
```

And could be used like so:

```
"Hello world!".whiteSpaceIndices    //[5]
"ä ö ü".whiteSpaceIndices           //[1, 3]
```

Comment: Note that your method returns other results than the original code. For the string `"ä ö ü"`  the original code returns `[1, 3]` and your code returns `[2, 5]`.

Comment: Btw, `char.isWhitespace` returns true for  newline characters, the `|| char.isNewline` is not needed.

Comment: Still different results for `" ‍⚖️ x"`

Comment: @MartinR from my limited knowledge, I think if we’d like to take emoji into consideration, we’ll have to revert to the code in question. Do share any trick if there is any.

Comment: The character/utf8/unicodeScalars *are* different and have different offsets. But it was not my intention to say that your code “does not work.” I just wanted to make you aware of the difference. It may not be relevant for OP (who did not provide more information about the text), but should be mentioned.

Comment: This for loop is better expressed as a `filer` expression